# Odd behaviour with links in PHP Mail function

Tags: php, email, hyperlink

I'm currently trying to get links working in emails sent via the PHP mail function. Here is my code - I've also included some things I've tried (commented out along with notes):

`$to = "test@testing.com";`

```
$subject = "Testing email";

//$body = '<strong>This is strong text</strong>';           <-- Works 
//and the text is correctly emphasised.

//$body = '<a href="www.yahoo.com">Link Test</a>';          <-- Works 
//but without http:// at the start makes the link relative to the server root

//$body = "<a href='http://www.yahoo.com'>Link Test</a>";   <-- Does not work

//$body = "<a href=\"http://www.yahoo.com\">Link Test</a>"; <-- Does not work

$body = '<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Link Test</a>'; //<-- Does not work

$headers =          "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .=         "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$headers .=         "From: Steven Parler <". $to . ">\r\n";
$headers .=         "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion() . "\r\n";

 if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
 }
```

As can be seen html is working without links, and links also work providing I don't include "http://" in the link itself. If I do include the "http://" then no email is received / sent at all (I'm unsure which as the mail() command returns true to say it was sent).

I'm not really sure why this isn't working. Could it be some setting that needs changing on my webhost's server? I'm on windows shared hosting.

Thanks in advance for any advice anyone can give me - been pulling my hair out over this lol. :)

Comment: What does it do? Do you not receive the message at all?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. Yes - in the ones noted as "Does not work" no email at all is received.

Comment: How links work, and if they work at all, is determined by the *client*, not the sever sending the message.

Answer (score 3):

Don't build MIME messages by hand. It's just too painful and fragile. Use something like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) to do it for your automatically. You provide the HTML, they'll provide the appropriate headers

Comment: Thanks for the reply - yes I'm going to try out one of those (trying phpmailer first) and hopefully it'll solve it. I'd still be interested if anyone knew what the problem is, simply as it's been bugging me so long hehe :)

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with @Marc B.

Here are a couple more options: [XPertMailer](http://www.xpertmailer.com/), [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html), [Rmail](http://www.phpguru.org/downloads/Rmail/Rmail%20for%20PHP/), [HTML MIME MAIL](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9-PHP-PHP-mailer-to-compose-and-send-MIME-messages.html)

I've worked with all of these but since I'm working mostly with the Zend Framework I'm lately using Zend_Mail.

Having said that, your hosting provider might be blocking your emails because they might think it's SPAM. Try generating valid html markup that [passes validation](http://validator.w3.org/) and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for response :) I will definitely try out these email php addons. I did previously try creating the email with full validation but it didn't help sadly. I do think it might be my host blocking something as I tried sending an email to the address with a body of simply "http://www.yahoo.com" from my yahoo email and it didn't arrive. Sending from the same email with no link was received just fine. Strangely however, if I send an email from the email on the webhost to itself, it goes through with links. Which is strange as essentially I'm doing that via php.

Comment: @Steven. Could you post the headers in the emails that did make it through to your account? There could be a clue there as to some sort of SPAM filtering going on. Look for stuff like X-GMX-Antispam, X-Spam-Status, X-Spam-Level, X-Spam-Checker-Version, and X-Spam-Flag. By the way all these libraries will enable you to send email though an external email account so you could create a Gmail account and have your website send through that if your hosting provider is giving you trouble.

Answer (score 0):

That's very odd behaviour, I'd expect the last 2 to work perfectly. I tried this out on my server, and `mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);` worked perfectly with a `$body` of

`text text text: \n http://website.com`.

Perhaps it's a setting somewhere? If you're using awardspace, they require a from header to be used, and the mail sent from an e-mail registered with them. Other hosts might have a similar procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses. I finally got around it by using the SMTP feature of Swiftmailer which correctly created the email with links.

Out of interest I tried the code I used in my original post again... but this time I used a random web address (http://www.trustedreviews.com). The email arrived... I then tried a lot of other web addresses - google.com, hotmail, yahoo.co.uk etc and they all arrived. Changed it back to (http://www.yahoo.com) and lo and behold the message did not arrive again. So it seems out of the millions of web URL's there are I chose the one that my webhost has decided to block lol...

That said the yahoo link does arrive ok using the smtp function of swift mail; it's only with the php mail function it doesn't seem to work. I guess I'll contact them and ask why it's blocked. I'll most likely stick with using the smtp method as at least it seems like it bypasses any restrictions.

Thanks again for everyone's time and help :)